# Fecha 12/22/2017 12:00 AM a 2017-12-22 12:00:00

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de actualizar fechas en MYSQL según los datos que me proporciona un formulario Datepicker. `(12/22/2017 12:00 AM)`

La función que me inserta los datos y modifica el formato es la siguiente:

```
public function changeDateBegin(){

    $dateBegin  = $_POST['dateBegin'];
    $id         = $_POST['taskId'];

    $fecha = strtotime($dateBegin);

    $fecha2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $fecha );

    $data = array(
        'dateBegin' => $fecha2, 
        );

    $this->db->where('taskId', $id);
    $this->db->update('task', $data);

    echo $fecha2;

}
```

Pero me devuelve `2017-12-22 00:00:00.`

¿Podría obtener la fecha correcta cambiando el formato de "date"?¿ o tengo que usar explode para poder transformarlo?¿ y si es así como cambio `12:00 AM` a `12:00:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [DateTimeFormat](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) aplicando los [formatos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) que quieras.

Ojo: En el formato 24 horas, 12:00 AM equivale a medianoche (00:00), si quieres que te lo presente como 12:00 tendrás que usar el formato de 12 horas (h).

Ejemplo:

[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/SXADH77324)

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

$date = new DateTime("12/22/2017 12:00 AM");

$date1 = new DateTime("12/22/2017 12:00 PM");

$date2 = new DateTime("12/22/2017 1:00 AM");

$date3 = new DateTime("12/22/2017 1:00 PM");


echo "Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 AM: 12 horas (h) -> " .$date->format('d-m-Y h:i:s')."\n";
echo "Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 AM: 24 horas (H) -> " .$date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')."\n";

echo "Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 PM: 12 horas (h) -> " .$date1->format('d-m-Y h:i:s')."\n";
echo "Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 PM: 24 horas (H) -> " .$date1->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')."\n";


echo "Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 1  AM: 12 horas (h) -> " .$date2->format('d-m-Y h:i:s')."\n";
echo "Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 1  PM: 24 horas (H) -> " .$date3->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')."\n";

?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 AM: 12 horas (h) -> 22-12-2017 12:00:00
Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 AM: 24 horas (H) -> 22-12-2017 00:00:00
Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 PM: 12 horas (h) -> 22-12-2017 12:00:00
Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 12 PM: 24 horas (H) -> 22-12-2017 12:00:00
Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 1  AM: 12 horas (h) -> 22-12-2017 01:00:00
Formato fecha: dd-mm-yyyy * Hora 1  PM: 24 horas (H) -> 22-12-2017 13:00:00
```

### Muy importante

Si los datos son para almacenarlos en la base de datos, te recomiendo que los almacenes **sin formato** y que el formato se lo des en la salida. Almacenar datos formateados en la base de datos (sobre todo fechas), no es buena idea, ya que muchas veces necesitamos presentar dichos datos en formatos diversos o necesitamos hacer cálculos con ellos. Si los mismos están formateados en el origen cualquiera de estas operaciones nos resultarían complicadas. Y los cálculos no podrían hacerse directamente sobre los datos, habría que leerlos, convertirlos y luego calcular lo cual, además de tedioso, podría resultar erróneo.